# When I redirect from products to products/details url is showing a wrong ID

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to redirect from the list of products to a `product-details` page, but my URL is showing a wrong value for ID:

for instance: https://cafe-c3c52.firebaseapp.com/admin/products;node_=%5Bobject%20Object%5D;ref_=https:%2F%2Fcafe-c3c52.firebaseio.com%2Fproducts%2F-LNpWrMiZ8YRAiaf8K9q;index_=.priority

The correct would be:  https://cafe-c3c52.firebaseapp.com/admin/products/id

Can you help me with figuring out what is wrong:

**admin-products.component.html**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
    <td>{{p.title}}</td>
    <td>{{p.price}}</td>
    <td><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]"> Edit</a> </td>
    <td> {{p.key}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**admin-products-component.ts**

```
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products$;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();
  }
  ...
}
```

**products.form.component**

```
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.productService.get(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
    }
  }
}
```

**product.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload,
          ...c.payload.val()
        }));
      });
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're using `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');`. Ideally you should be subscribing to `this.route.params` which is a `BehaviorSubject` to get the updated id.

Also, you should try to keep your `constructor`s as light weight as possible. So please consider moving your `constructor` code to `ngOnInit`

Change your `ProductsFormComponent` implementation like this

```
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        const id = params['id'];
        if (id) {
          this.productService.get(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: HI @SiddAjmera, tks for answering, I change the code as you said but the url still is showing  admin/products/invalid ... I don't know why...